# Not able to print the list of all Docker image tags in GCP Artifact Registry using google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1beta2 API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to fetch all existing images based on GCP Artifact Registry using Python `google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1beta2` API. My codes:

```
def list_all_repositories(project):
    locations = ['northamerica-northeast1']
    repositories = []
    for location in locations:
        parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
        repositories_in_location = client.list_repositories(parent=parent)
        repositories.extend(repositories_in_location)

    return repositories
# Set up client
repositories = list_all_repositories(project)


def list_images(repository_name):
    # Set up client
    parent = repository_name
    #tag_filter = f"tags:{tag_prefix}*"

    # List Docker images with the specified tag prefix
    docker_images = client.list_tags(parent=parent)
    print(docker_images)


    # Sort images by creation time in descending order
    sorted_images = sorted(docker_images, key=lambda img: img.create_time, reverse=True)

    print(sorted_images)

for repository in repositories:
    print(f"Checking repository: {repository.name}")
    list_images(repository_name=repository.name)
```

But getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 910, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.13.138:443 {created_time:"2023-05-02T09:58:29.859773-04:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Request contains an invalid argument."}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mdrahman/Desktop/Desktop - Md’s MacBook Pro/noze/model_version_access/dummy/test.py", line 43, in <module>
    list_images(repository_name=repository.name)
  File "/Users/mdrahman/Desktop/Desktop - Md’s MacBook Pro/noze/model_version_access/dummy/test.py", line 31, in list_images
    docker_images = client.list_tags(parent=parent)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/artifactregistry_v1beta2/services/artifact_registry/client.py", line 2380, in list_tags
    response = rpc(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 349, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 191, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.
```

I understand the error traceback shows that the issue is related to the list_tags function call, which is invoked with the argument parent=parent. It's possible that the value of the parent is not a valid input for the list_tags function. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Your problem is `Permission denied on resource project ai-model-training-library`

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thank you, I have overcome the Permission denied error. But still getting the `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I have edited the question with the new error.

Comment: On Stack Overflow one problem per post. Once you solve the first problem, post the solution. Then create a new post. Back out your post edit, post the solution, and create a new post with the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Parent should be a package for ListTags, not a Repository (if you want to search the hierarchy like this, you need one more loop that calls ListPackages). We're updating this to make it more clear

Side-note: you should generally use v1 instead of v1beta2 for the AR api. V1beta2 is only still around for backwards compatibility

-James (Google Engineer)